# VBA Iterating through pivot table slicer items and selecting item if item name equals a value

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, slicers

I am trying to write a VBA procedure that will loop through the slicer items for 6 pivot table caches (each with different data sources) and evaluate if each slicer item name is equal to a previously defined variable value.

When I run this code I am getting a Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error on the first line of the For loop. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong as it seems like this code works for others.

```
    Sub Generate_Consultant_Dashboard()
'
' Generate_Consultant_Dashboard Macro
'

'
Dim sC1 As SlicerCache
Dim sC2 As SlicerCache
Dim sC3 As SlicerCache
Dim sC4 As SlicerCache
Dim sC5 As SlicerCache
Dim sC6 As SlicerCache
Dim sI As SlicerItem
Dim wS As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("NameSlicerSheet").Visible = True
    Sheets("NameSlicerSheet").Select
    errorCount = Range("B2").Value
'Check for errors
    If errorCount > 1 Then
        'Error'
        'Tell the user how many errors there are and to only choose one consultant.'
        Sheets("NameSlicerSheet").Visible = False
        Sheets("Staff Select").Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "Error " & errorCount & " Consultants selected. Only select one Consultant and retry."
    Else
        Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NameSlicerSheet")

        wS.Select
        Range("B1").Select
        Consultant = Selection

        Set sC1 = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Staff_Name")
        sC1.ClearAllFilters
        For Each sI In sC1.SlicerItems
            If sI.Name = Consultant Then
                sI.Selected = True
            Else
                sI.Selected = False
            End If
        Next sI
```

The code then goes through the other 5 slicer cache's to do the same thing. I just cut off that part as I can't get past the first for loop line.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to change `Dim sI As SlicerItem` to `Dim sI As Variant`. Also note whenever you feel you need to number variables `sC1` to `sC6` make sure to use arrays instead `Dim sC(1 To 6)` and use the variable like `sC(1)`. Advantage is you can use a loop to loop through those variables and don't need to repeat code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried updating per your suggestions and unfortunately still getting the same run-time error on the same For loop line.

Comment: After doing a bit more research I've determined that it is a bit more complicated, because some of the slicers in my NameSlicerSheet are connected to the Data Model (Power Pivot) and some are not. Different syntax is likely required for the different types of pivot tables.